# Identify 4 pin Connector

Tags: connector, identification

I need to get some more of this connector and solder my own cables however I can't find this exact one online.

It looks like some variant of JST but from looking up the different types of JST I can't find one that matches this.

The cable came with a [LiDAR sensor](https://www.robotshop.com/uk/benewake-tfmini-micro-lidar-module-12-m.html). One end is a JST SH 1mm and the other end is the connector I'm having trouble finding.

Can anyone help identify this connector?

#### Male end

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

#### Female end

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a **Male JST GH 4 pin connector "crimp style" with 1.25mm spacing** as found [here](http://www.jst.co.uk/productSeries.php?pid=11517&cat=30) (download the catalogue page).

Part NO: `GHR-04V-S`